# How to use a jade template to accept information from multiple sources and display with include statements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, include, express, pug

I have this template:

```
.bar
  .titleBox
    a.title(href=URL) #{title}
```

Which I want to include multiple times in another page, titles.jade, like so:

```
#contentBox
  include bar
  include bar
  include bar
```

And I want each one to have a different value for URL and title.

I have this code in node:

```
read(function(post){ //post is an array of objects retrieved from a mongodb collection
    // I was thinking of using a for loop to iterate through the array
    res.render('titles', {title: post[i].title, url: post[i].URL});
```

How might I achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what these objects represent, but I'll assume for now we are talking about books. If your jade template can get a list of books as a local - e.g. if it's redered like:

```
res.render('books_index', {books: [{title: 'dune', url: 'http://www.dunenovels.com'},...]})
```

You can use a [mixin](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a14). Something like this:

```
mixin listBooks(books)
  each book in books
    .bar
      .titleBox
        a.title(href=book.url)= book.title
```

later in your template you can render the mixin:

```
mixin listBooks(books)
```

Comment: This solution helped me a lot, but can I use mixin to display info for different books on different jade pages?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm answering your question, but you can put the mixin in its own file and include it like any other template. Then, any page which benefits from listing books can just include the mixin and use it. The rendered contents would of course depend on the value of `books` at the time that particular view was rendered.